# How to encode URI in XSL of the XML Viewer Web Part?

Tags: xslt, xml-viewer-web-part

I am using the XML Viewer Web Part to display some links. I need to encode the URI component because a value of a parameter may contain and ampersand. The way to do this in XSLT 2.0 is by using fn:encode-for-uri(). However, as soon as I add this to the XSL, the web part returns the error:

Failed to apply XSLT to the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using JavaScript to handle the encoding, since it seems to be the only option. Passing XSL variables to JavaScript and then outputting the link with document.write().

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        <xsl:text>var urlPrefix = "</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$urlPrefix"/><xsl:text>";</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>var valueToEncode = "</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$valueToEncode"/><xsl:text>";</xsl:text>
        <![CDATA[document.write("<a href='"+urlPrefix+encodeURIComponent(valueToEncode)+"'>link text</a>");]]>
    </script>
```

Note that if your valueToEncode may contain quotes ("), you need to take additional measures.

Answer (score 1):

In SharePoint we have XSLT 1.0, so the 2.0 functions obviously will not work.

Instead, you can use some SharePoint stuff, and in this particular situation **ddwrt:UrlEncode** extension function will probably help you. For details, please, read following MSDN article:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd583143(v=office.11).aspx#officesharepointddwrt_urlencode

Comment: 1.0? that's odd because as if I change the version from 2.0 to 1.0, the XSLT stops working. I've considered ddwrt, but haven't figured if I can use it in an XML web part, and if so, how. I'll try this: http://blogs.pointbridge.com/Blogs/johnson_bert/Pages/Post.aspx?_ID=5

Comment: In my case `version="1.0"`, applied to the `<xsl:stylesheet>`, works fine. However, ddwrt functions don't seem to work there, even if I provide correct namespace. After some investigations, including even Reflector, turns out, that the XmlWebPart is actually a very odd webpart and it is separated completely from all other SharePoint Xslt webparts, like DVWP, XLV, CQWP, etc. So I confess, my answer is wrong: you can't use ddwrt:UrlEncode in XML Viewer. I'll try to find another solution.

Comment: I was just playing with it and came to the same conclusion. Was able to switch to 1.0 as well; error must have been dues to something else.

Comment: Ended up using JavaScript and it works.

Comment: This worked for my SharePoint 2010 xslt. Was able to paste <xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:UrlEncode(@Title)"/> directly into my custom DisplayForm.aspx page. No JS required for my purposes

Comment: FWIW- In my scenario I am building out my anchor tag via XML: <a><xsl:attribute name='href'>http:/ /baseHref?querystrParam=<xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:UrlEncode(@Title)"/></xsl:attribute></a>

Answer (score -1):

could you not use an xml editor that covers xslt 1.0 and 2.0 like [liquid xml editor](http://www.liquid-technologies.com/xml-editor.aspx)?

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint! Since this is your first post, I'm not familiar with your account. We require relevant answers and disclosure of any affiliation with products or websites. Please see [May I promote products or websites I am affiliated with here?](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion) for guidelines.